# Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, buffer

I want to run a Discord bot, but this code is using Buffer and it keeps producing an error for this code:

```
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    if((new Buffer(req.query.key, "base64")).toString("utf-8") == key && req.query.message) {
        let message = (new Buffer(req.query.message, "base64")).toString("utf-8");
        onWebhookMessage(message);
    }
})

app.listen(3000);

module.exports = {getClient:function(){return client;}};
```

And this is the error:

```
(node:600332) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined
    at Function.from (buffer.js:330:9)
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:286:17)
    at /root/bot/index.js:182:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

I've changed `new Buffer()` to `Buffer.from()` and it's not working. It produces this error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined
    at Function.from (buffer.js:330:9)
    at /root/bot/index.js:182:17
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/root/bot/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
```

I've updated Node.js (NPM not Yarn) to the latest version and the buffers too but still the same. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking whether `req.query.key` is actually a string. Your error reports you're doing `Buffer.from(undefined)`, which would happen if `req.query.key` is undefined.

Assuming that `key` should be a string, you can simply compare it directly. Therefore, something like this should be fine for your use case:

```js
if (req.query.key === key && typeof req.query.message === 'string') {
```

You don't even need to use `Buffer` here anymore, since `Buffer.from(str).toString('utf-8') === str`, as `utf8` is the [default encoding](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_from_string_encoding).